# Minimize a linear function over the unit ball

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

> Minimize a linear function over the unit ball. (without using Lagrangian)

We have a problem: minimize $c^Ty$ subject to $y^Ty \le 1$.

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have $c^Ty \le \|c\|_2\|y\|_2 \le \|c\|_2$. So, if the problem was to maximize we would get $c^Ty = \|c\|_2, y=  c/\|c\|_2$.

The answer to the problem is $y^{*} = -c/\|c\|_2$. However, I don't see how it can be derived. One thought is:

The problem is equivalent to: maximize $-c^Ty = (-c)^Ty$ subject to $y^Ty \le 1$.

$(-c)^Ty \le \|c\|_2, y = -c/\|c\|_2$

Comment: Your "one thought" is a perfectly clear solution to the problem.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz proves that $|c^Ty| \le \|c\|_2\, \|y\|_2$, so the problem of minimizing is exactly as easy as the problem of maximizing.

Comment: Let's minimize $c^T y$ where $y$ is restricted to be a unit vector. The Cauchy-Schwartz inequality also tells us that $c^T y \geq -\| c \| \| y \|$. If $y$ is a unit vector, then the smallest possible value of $c^T y$ is $- \| c \|$. This smallest possible value is attained when $y = -c/\|c\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the Lagrangian of the problem:
$\mathcal{L}(y, \lambda) = c^T y - \lambda(y^Ty - 1)$ with $\lambda$ the dual variable associated with the constraint.
The optimality conditions are:
$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} = c - 2 \lambda y = 0$
$y^Ty \le 1$
$\lambda(y^Ty - 1) = 0$
$\lambda \le 0$

We must have $\lambda < 0$ (constraint is active at the solution: $y^T y = 1$), so $y = \frac{c}{2 \lambda}$, which we inject in the 3rd equation, solve for $\lambda$, substitute in $y$ and we get the result.

Comment: It's overkill to use the KKT conditions though because we can see the answer directly. $y$ should point in the direction opposite to $c$, of course.

Comment: I wrote that I can't use the Lagrangian. However, thank you for your contribution. I saw the answer to my question in the comments section. However, I will accept your answer since it also gives a perspective about how to tackle the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let us remember that $c^\mathsf{T}y$ is a dot product and the dot product is a projection of one vector over the other as the following picture shows. (More info in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Scalar_projection_and_first_properties))

[image: dot product]

Intuitively, if we were to minimize the problem and we have a fixed vector $c$, we need to go to the direction contrary to $c$, so that the projection is entirely in the span of $c$, and so the dot product will always be negative (or zero when $c$ is the zero vector).

Now that we have a negative value, let's see the constraint which is $y^\mathsf{T}y \leq 1$, which is the same as the quadratic norm $\lVert y \rVert_2^2\leq 1$, if we want the value of $c^\mathsf{T}y$ to be as negative as possible, we need to have as much magnitude as we can, this is going to happen when we saturate the constraint to $\lVert y \rVert_2^2= 1$.

Considering the two previous sentences, this happens when $y=-c/\lVert c \rVert_2$, this is the normalized vector $c$ going on the opposite direction as desired.

Finaly, result of the minimization is going to be as follows.

$$
c^\mathsf{T}y= -\frac{c^\mathsf{T}c}{\lVert c \rVert_2} = -\frac{\lVert c \rVert_2^2}{\lVert c \rVert_2} =-\lVert c \rVert_2
$$